# слой DAL без использования ORM

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orm, repository

Пытаюсь реализовать веб-сервис с использованием ASP.NET с базой данный PostGreSQL. DAL должен быть без использования ORM. Прочитала много информации и немного запуталась: не использовать ORM означает, что я не буду создавать объекты для данных с базы, верно? Нашла паттерн с использованием репозиториев [с таким примером реализации](https://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/creating-a-repository-pattern-without-an-orm-A9) , но не могу разобраться в реализации метода PopulateRecord. В общем, любая информация была бы полезной :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без ORM - не значит, что вы не будете создавать объекты базы данных. Без использования ORM в данном случае означает не использовать Entity Framework или Hibernate, или их подобия. Но вам все равно придется:

1. Создавать базу данных в ручную
2. Писать запросы/функции/процедуры/представления для сервера
3. Вызывать и обрабатывать команды с приложения
4. Создать объектную модель и/либо модель представления для работы с базой

По сути вы будете сами контролировать работу с базой данных. Есть масса плюсов и минусов, но как видите это не меняет общих требований при работе с БД.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ваш ответ помог двигаться в правильном пути

Comment: @Yulia если вам помог этот ответ, вы можете отметить его принятым, галочка расположена слева от ответа.

Comment: @Yulia Фактически вам придётся делать "вручную" всё то, что мог бы за вас сделать ORM. )